# HTTPS rewrite www

Tags: nginx

Nginx redirects all HTTP to HTTPS with the WWW appended, like-so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ...
}
```

When "https://example.com" is visited, I receive an SSL_Common_Name error referring to the default_server. Notice how it is HTTPS without WWW. I need to force WWW on HTTPS, would I want to rewrite in this case?

How can I effectively return/rewrite the URL when visited?
I need HTTPS without WWW to return HTTPS with WWW.

Is the following correct? If so, should I remove "ssl http2" from the first server block?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ...
}
```

I appreciate your time with this.

Comment: You can remove http2 from 2nd block, but you need to keep ssl. Rest all looks good

Comment: Thank you Tarun... Not sure why I took so long to reply. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove http2 from 2nd block as it is not needed, but you need to keep ssl.

Rest all looks good